# use taylor series formula for $g(x,y)$ at origin and finding quadratic approximation of $g(0.1,0.2)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Use taylor series formula for $$g(x,y)=e^x\ln(2x+y+1)$$ at origin to find a quadratic approximation of $g\bigg(\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{5}\bigg)$

What i try:

$g_{x}(x,y)=\frac{2e^x}{2x+y+1}+\ln(2x+y+1)e^x$ and $g(0)=2$

$g_{y}(x,y)=\frac{e^x}{2x+y+1}$. and $g_{x,y}(0,0)=1$

$g_{xx}(x,y)=\frac{(2x+y+1)2e^{x}-2e^{x}(2x)}{(2x+y+1)^2}+\frac{2e^x}{2x+y+1}+\ln(2x+y+1)e^x$ and $g_{xx}(0,0)=4$

$g_{yy}(x,y)=-\frac{e^x}{(2x+y+1)^2}$ and $g_{yy}(0,0)=-1$

And $g_{xy}(x,y)=\frac{(2x+y+1)e^x-e^x(y)}{(2x+y+1)^2}$ and $g_{xy}(0,0)=1$

And quadratic formula

$$Q(x,y)=L(x,y)+g_{xx}(0,0)\frac{(x-0)^2}{2}+g_{xy}(0,0)(x-0)(y-0)+g_{yy}(0,0)\frac{(y-0)^2}{2}$$

I did not understand How can i find Quadratic approximation of $g(1/10,1/5)$. Help me please

Comment: I would have make a Taylor on $ g(x, y)$ at order 2 on $x$ then on $y$ relatively to (1/10) and (1/5). And majorating the second order gradient norm of $g$

Comment: Thanks but still i did not understand. Please explain me in detail

Comment: I make an anwser for you )

Answer (score 1):

First we want to develop it at the origin :

Let $$A=(1/10,1/5) $$

We have generally at the second order ( in $ \mathbb{R}^2$ )

$$g(A)\simeq g(0)+\nabla g(0) A+ \dfrac{1}{2}H_g(0)(A)A^t$$

Where

$$H_g(0)(A)=D(Dg(A))(A)$$

denote the **Hessian matrix** of $g$ matrix of second derivatives of $g$.

---

Then :

$$\nabla g(0)(A)=A \begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{2}{5}$$

And :

$$H_g(x)=DD_g(x) $$
Then
$$ H_g(0)(A)=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 \\
1 & -1\end{pmatrix}A^t=\begin{pmatrix} 2 &\dfrac{-1}{10}\end{pmatrix} $$

Finally :

$$g(1/10,1/5)\simeq 2 +\dfrac{2}{5}+\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{9}{50}=2.49$$